# foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble editing the data in mysql with foreigh keys. When I try to update a foreign key, it says:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sadsystem/products`, CONSTRAINT `fk_ProductRelationship11` FOREIGN KEY (`size_id`) REFERENCES `product_sizes` (`size_id`))

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing this is [`SET CONSTRAINTS DEFERRED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9/static/sql-set-constraints.html).

However, MySQL/InnoDB does not support this. You will have to edit your data in consistency order: that is, you'll first have to create the target row in `product_sizes` before you can refer to its `size_id` from other tables.

(If you're sure you know what you're doing (such as when importing data), you can also temporarily disable the [foreign_key_checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) setting, but this does **not** check referential integrity when you re-enable it: any constraints broken while it was disabled will stay broken.)

Comment: please enlighten me more. i am not good in mysql. i do these because its part of my minor programming subject. how can i do these in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

When you update a column which is part (or all) of a foreign key, then the new value of the complete foreign key must reference a row in the referenced table.  The error message is saying you are attempting to update the foreign key to a value that does not exist in the referenced table.

Comment: i am really confused right now. you can see my detailed question regarding editing of foreign keys. please take time to read and study the codes i posted there. thank you very much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844591/inner-join-passing-data-from-table-for-edit